# как используя onClick оставить валидацию полей (text, email)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Есть форма. 
В ней следующие поля (*FirstName, LastName, Company, Email, Password*) + кнопка с Onclick (отправка данных на сервер).

У всех полей прописан параметр 'required', а для

```
email pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$".
```

Вшитая в HTML5 валидация не работает с Onclick. Как можно исправить это?

Comment: использовать onSubmit

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как используя onClick оставить валидацию полей (text, email)?

Вот так используя событий `submit`:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // Не посылает на сервер
  e.preventDefault();
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Проверка mail
  var mail = document.querySelector('.mail');
  var re = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}$/;

  if (re.test(mail.value)) { // Если прошел
    console.log('Passes');
  } else{
   console.error('You shall not pass!');
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Так же можете проверять и text
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="mail">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло!